# Mongoose documents find by object _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have mongoose model like this:

```
const ChatRoomSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    roomId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    sender: {
      _id: { type: String },
      name: { type: String },
      dp: { type: String },
    },
    receiver: {
      _id: { type: String },
      name: { type: String },
      dp: { type: String },
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

Now i want find documents by this query:

```
const rooms = await ChatRoom.find({sender: {_id: userId }})    // it return the document if 
                                                                  sender itself a _id, 
                                                                   but its a object.
```

It returns an empty array. How can I find the document throw the sender object's _id field?

Comment: try to use dot notation when you match object property `{ "sernder._id": userId }`.

Comment: Tried it, can not use dot inside find query

Comment: you can use in find query, what is the error?